# Why would one write a literal directly followed by a semicolon in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm looking at some code and I've come across the following line in a macro:

```
int foo = 0; (foo);
```

It compiles just fine. In fact, it seems that

```
0;
```

is a valid line of code in C/C++.

I've taken a look at the produced assembly in debug and release builds (on msvc), and it does not make a difference to the assembly. My test was a simple one though (with and without `(foo);`):

```
int main()
{
    int foo = 0;
    (foo);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why would anyone want to do this? I'm sure `(foo);` is in the macro for a reason, but I'm not sure why.

For context, the macro it is found in looks like this (I've renamed the variables):

```
#define MY_MACRO int _foo = 0; (_foo); UINT _bar = CP_THREAD_ACP; (_bar); LPCWSTR _baz = NULL; (_baz); LPCSTR _thing = NULL; (_thing)
```

In the code, it is simply called like

```
MY_MACRO;
//other code...
```

Comment: Probably to suppress any "unused variable" compile warnings.

Comment: But couldn't it produce a warning about ignoring a result? I thought the right way to do so was `(void) (foo);` @FredLarson

Comment: @Justin: C and C++ code ignore results all the time, especially in function calls. Such a warning would be extremely unpopular.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, but I seem to recall that one should cast it to `void`. I can't remember where I got that.... Maybe it was just because if you had something like `foo, bar`, C++ could have an overloaded `operator,`, so you'd want to cast to void. I probably just overgeneralized that

Comment: Thanks. I have to say, that's one odd macro.

Comment: This looks like a macro that declares a bunch of variables "just in case I'm gonna need them" with associated "unused variable" suppression in case they're not needed. It doesn't seem very useful other than for obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

As Fred Larson suggested in the comments, it could be used to suppress compiler warnings. I tried this code:

```
int foo = 0;
foo;
```

I debugged the code and the compiler completely skipped over the second line, so it seems to do nothing of importance. Of course if you are afraid that these lines affect your macro, you can always step through the code with a debugger like I did.

Comment: it is done to suppress the warning unused variable. But it is done improperly so you can get another one instead (initialized variable ). It shoud be `(void)foo;`

Answer (score 0):

It might be the result of macro expansion.

It might just be someone being silly.

It could be to suppress compiler warnings.

In any case, statements like that are perfectly legal in the language and have no actual effect on the program.
Any competent compiler will just remove them during compilation.

Comment: it is done to suppress the warning unused variable. But it is done improperly so you can get another one instead (initialized variable). It shoud be `(void)foo;`